# Do I need to release the event handler which I bind through fromEvent operator?

Tags: rxjs

```
fromEvent(document, 'visibilitychange').subscribe(() => doSomething());
```

I'd like to bind an event to the document with `fromEvent` operator and I'm wondering if I need to remove/unbind the handler with `takeUntil` or by unsubscribing it on the destroy phase. I've come to learn that event handlers are released when the element they are binded with is removed from DOM but in this case, since I bind the handler on `document`, I feel like having to release it on my own but I'm not sure. Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know when Dom node is removed from the document tree the associated event will be removed, however since the event is binded by using rxjs `fromEvent`, you will still need to unsubscribe to prevent memory leak.

Regarding the document node, by looking into the source code of `fromEvent`, it will invoke removeEventListener for you upon your unsubscription. Again you will need to invoke unsubscribe when you no longer need it.

```
function setupSubscription(sourceObj, eventName, handler, subscriber, options) {
    let unsubscribe;
    if (isEventTarget(sourceObj)) {
        const source = sourceObj;
        sourceObj.addEventListener(eventName, handler, options);
        unsubscribe = () => source.removeEventListener(eventName, handler, options);
    }
```